# Ionic can't install @ionic/cloud, NPM says Not found

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I'm trying to install @ionic/cloud package using npm
, my Ionic ClI version is: 2.0.0

The following npm error displayed:

```
user@ub-dev01:/opt/lampp/htdocs/ess_app$ npm install @ionic/cloud --save
npm WARN package.json ess_app@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ess_app@1.1.1 No README data
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'ionic/cloud' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ess_app'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-45-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "@ionic/cloud" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /opt/lampp/htdocs/ess_app
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/lampp/htdocs/ess_app/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I tried sudo, also not working

Comment: I remove @ still not working, the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by updating npm itself, by running

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for @ionic/cloud-angular? `npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save` (may need `sudo`)

http://docs.ionic.io/setup.html

Comment: I tried sudo, but I solved it by udate npm itself to allow it to refresh its registry.